How to set port number in Python Package manager Anaconda Navigator
Every time, I launch Anaconda-Navigator it is open in a new port. I want to set or fix the port number when I launch it.
I have searched the documentation a bit, however, I did not find anything or I might miss.
Does anyone know how to set the port number while launching the Anaconda-navigator?
Note
OS: Ubuntu
